# Shell running inside vim windows

Tags: buffers, tabbed-user-interface, bash, window-management, shell

Is there a way that a open up a window or buffer, where i can run my bash commands? I thought on something like you know it from VS Code([1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNyAc.png)). The code windows on the top and a small command prompt on the bottom of the view, where i can run for example my rails or node server?

[image: VS Code]

> For more clearity I want an editor on the top and a command prompt on the bottom of the window, where I can switch using  commands. On the terminal should run a long running part.

Comment: You could use `tmux` and put vim in one window.

Comment: That's exactly what I would like to avoid. Some times I need some registers and <C-w> commands to jump through terminal and editor.

Comment: `:terminal` command added in version 8.1 https://www.vim.org/vim-8.1-released.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need Vim 8.1, then you can use the following command:

```
:below terminal ++rows=10
```

Normally a terminal is opened above the current window, but with `below` it is opened at the bottom. And in this case, the terminal should have a height of 10 rows.

See `:help :terminal` for additional `++`-options.

Answer (score 1):

For older Vim versions, there is [Conque Shell](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2771), a no-longer-supported plugin which nevertheless has served me well in the past, and for now, continues to do so. It's still provided by e.g. `vim-addons`, which makes it really easy to add to your setup.

You can start a `bash` (or any other command, really...) using the current window as terminal:

```
:ConqueTerm bash
```

Personally I have the following two corresponding lines in my `~/.vimrc`:

```
let g:ConqueTerm_CWInsert = 1      " Allow <C-w> to switch buffer without leaving insert mode
let g:ConqueTerm_InsertOnEnter = 1 " Automatically enter insert mode when switching to Conque buffer
```